# Static Ports In Django w/ Visual Studio

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

Has anyone found out a way to have visual studio run a Django app on a static port rather than it changing ports every run? I have a separate program sending requests to the server but it becomes a hassle having to change the port every time I re run the server.

Thanks in advance for any direction on the subject.

Comment: Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Solution Properties -> Debug Tab

In the Run Section, change Launch URL with the IP value and port that you need.

e.g: http//localhost:5555